# After deploying my Gatsby frontend to Netlify, my product specific pages are being hidden after loading successfully

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, gatsby, netlify

For clarification, all this has occurred for the first time after I have successfully deployed my Gatsby project to Netlify.

My problem can be clearly seen here: https://jamstack-marketplace.netlify.app/
And you will notice that when you visit a product like i.e. : https://jamstack-marketplace.netlify.app/hats/bucket?style=M - or any product specific page for that matter, it will load successfully, but will suddenly ***hide the product page***

Again just for clarification, I have it perfectly connected to my strapi backend which is successfully deployed on an AWS EC2 Instance here: http://54.67.112.47:1337/

For good measure, I have included the entire response from Netlify during the deploy of the Gatsby project... it is as follows:

```
5:38:13 PM: ​
5:38:13 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:38:13 PM:   Netlify Build                                                 
5:38:13 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:38:13 PM: ​
5:38:13 PM: ❯ Version
5:38:13 PM:   @netlify/build 18.13.6
5:38:13 PM: ​
5:38:13 PM: ❯ Flags
5:38:13 PM:   baseRelDir: true
5:38:13 PM:   buildId: 6158fb2fb482a30008c813df
5:38:13 PM:   deployId: 6158fb2fb482a30008c813e1
5:38:13 PM: ​
5:38:13 PM: ❯ Current directory
5:38:13 PM:   /opt/build/repo
5:38:13 PM: ​
5:38:13 PM: ❯ Config file
5:38:13 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
5:38:13 PM: ​
5:38:13 PM: ❯ Context
5:38:13 PM:   production
5:38:13 PM: ​
5:38:13 PM: ❯ Installing plugins
5:38:13 PM:    - @netlify/plugin-gatsby@1.0.3
5:38:20 PM: ​
5:38:20 PM: ❯ Loading plugins
5:38:20 PM:    - @netlify/plugin-gatsby@1.0.3 from Netlify app
5:38:21 PM: ​
5:38:21 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:38:21 PM:   1. onPreBuild command from @netlify/plugin-gatsby             
5:38:21 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:38:21 PM: ​
5:38:21 PM: No Gatsby cache found. Building fresh.
5:38:21 PM: Add `gatsby-plugin-netlify` to `gatsby-config.js` if you would like to support Gatsby redirects. 
5:38:21 PM: ​
5:38:21 PM: (@netlify/plugin-gatsby onPreBuild completed in 191ms)
5:38:21 PM: ​
5:38:21 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:38:21 PM:   2. Build command from Netlify app                             
5:38:21 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:38:21 PM: ​
5:38:21 PM: $ npm run build
5:38:21 PM: > JAMstack-Course@1.0.0 build
5:38:21 PM: > gatsby build
5:38:24 PM: warning Plugin gatsby-plugin-react-helmet is not compatible with your gatsby version 3.14.1 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
5:38:24 PM: warning Plugin gatsby-source-filesystem is not compatible with your gatsby version 3.14.1 - It requires gatsby@^2.2.0
5:38:25 PM: warning Plugin gatsby-plugin-offline is not compatible with your gatsby version 3.14.1 - It requires gatsby@^2.4.0
5:38:25 PM: warning Plugin gatsby-plugin-react-helmet is not compatible with your gatsby version 3.14.1 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
5:38:25 PM: warning Plugin gatsby-source-filesystem is not compatible with your gatsby version 3.14.1 - It requires gatsby@^2.2.0
5:38:25 PM: warning Plugin gatsby-plugin-offline is not compatible with your gatsby version 3.14.1 - It requires gatsby@^2.4.0
5:38:25 PM: success open and validate gatsby-configs, load plugins - 1.134s
5:38:25 PM: success onPreInit - 0.005s
5:38:25 PM: success initialize cache - 0.055s
5:38:25 PM: success copy gatsby files - 0.078s
5:38:25 PM: success Compiling Gatsby Functions - 0.332s
5:38:25 PM: success onPreBootstrap - 0.350s
5:38:26 PM: success createSchemaCustomization - 0.006s
5:38:26 PM: info Starting to fetch data from Strapi - http://54.67.112.47:1337/products with params {"_limit":1000}
5:38:26 PM: info Starting to fetch data from Strapi - http://54.67.112.47:1337/categories with params {"_limit":1000}
5:38:26 PM: info Starting to fetch data from Strapi - http://54.67.112.47:1337/variants with params {"_limit":1000}
5:38:29 PM: success Fetched Strapi Data - 3.088s
5:38:29 PM: success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
5:38:29 PM: success source and transform nodes - 3.856s
5:38:32 PM: success building schema - 2.771s
5:38:34 PM: success createPages - 1.746s
5:38:38 PM: success createPagesStatefully - 3.803s
5:38:38 PM: info Total nodes: 339, SitePage nodes: 19 (use --verbose for breakdown)
5:38:38 PM: success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
5:38:38 PM: success update schema - 0.393s
5:38:38 PM: success onPreExtractQueries - 0.000s
5:38:41 PM: success extract queries from components - 2.634s
5:38:41 PM: success write out redirect data - 0.005s
5:38:43 PM: success Build manifest and related icons - 0.568s
5:38:43 PM: success onPostBootstrap - 1.928s
5:38:43 PM: info bootstrap finished - 21.367s
5:38:43 PM: success run static queries - 0.430s - 4/4 9.30/s
5:38:45 PM: success run page queries - 1.395s - 19/19 13.62/s
5:38:45 PM: success write out requires - 0.467s
5:40:23 PM: success Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 98.259s
5:40:23 PM: success Rewriting compilation hashes - 0.078s
5:40:23 PM: success Writing page-data.json files to public directory - 0.115s - 19/19 165.01/s
5:40:41 PM: success Building HTML renderer - 17.906s
5:40:44 PM: These are the variants:  {
5:40:44 PM:   id: '61500b8003572d11aa5f9d60',
5:40:44 PM:   color: '#2A363B',
5:40:44 PM:   size: 'S',
5:40:44 PM:   style: 'M',
5:40:44 PM:   price: 49.99,
5:40:44 PM:   images: [ { localFile: [Object] } ]
5:40:44 PM: }
5:40:47 PM: These are the variants:  {
5:40:47 PM:   id: '614bacb28f449c8de13bb0d4',
5:40:47 PM:   color: '#FFF',
5:40:47 PM:   size: 'L',
5:40:47 PM:   style: 'M',
5:40:47 PM:   price: 12.99,
5:40:47 PM:   images: [ { localFile: [Object] } ]
5:40:47 PM: }
5:40:47 PM: These are the variants:  {
5:40:47 PM:   id: '614babe98f449c8de13bb0ca',
5:40:47 PM:   color: '#FFF',
5:40:47 PM:   size: 'L',
5:40:47 PM:   style: 'M',
5:40:47 PM:   price: 12.99,
5:40:47 PM:   images: [ { localFile: [Object] } ]
5:40:47 PM: }
5:40:47 PM: These are the variants:  {
5:40:47 PM:   id: '614baab58f449c8de13bb0c0',
5:40:47 PM:   color: '#FFF',
5:40:47 PM:   size: 'L',
5:40:47 PM:   style: 'M',
5:40:47 PM:   price: 12.99,
5:40:47 PM:   images: [ { localFile: [Object] } ]
5:40:47 PM: }
5:40:48 PM: These are the variants:  {
5:40:48 PM:   id: '61501a5d03572d11aa5f9da6',
5:40:48 PM:   color: '#2A363B',
5:40:48 PM:   size: 'L',
5:40:48 PM:   style: 'Female',
5:40:48 PM:   price: 24.99,
5:40:48 PM:   images: [ { localFile: [Object] } ]
5:40:48 PM: }
5:40:48 PM: These are the variants:  {
5:40:48 PM:   id: '6150192d03572d11aa5f9d92',
5:40:48 PM:   color: '#2A363B',
5:40:48 PM:   size: 'L',
5:40:48 PM:   style: 'Female',
5:40:48 PM:   price: 24.99,
5:40:48 PM:   images: [ { localFile: [Object] } ]
5:40:48 PM: }
5:40:48 PM: These are the variants:  {
5:40:48 PM:   id: '6150168303572d11aa5f9d7e',
5:40:48 PM:   color: '#2A363B',
5:40:48 PM:   size: 'M',
5:40:48 PM:   style: 'Male',
5:40:48 PM:   price: 24.99,
5:40:48 PM:   images: [ { localFile: [Object] } ]
5:40:48 PM: }
5:40:48 PM: These are the variants:  {
5:40:48 PM:   id: '61500cd003572d11aa5f9d74',
5:40:48 PM:   color: '#2A363B',
5:40:48 PM:   size: 'M',
5:40:48 PM:   style: 'M',
5:40:48 PM:   price: 49.99,
5:40:48 PM:   images: [ { localFile: [Object] } ]
5:40:48 PM: }
5:40:48 PM: These are the variants:  {
5:40:48 PM:   id: '61500c4903572d11aa5f9d6a',
5:40:48 PM:   color: '#E84A5F',
5:40:48 PM:   size: 'L',
5:40:48 PM:   style: 'M',
5:40:48 PM:   price: 49.99,
5:40:48 PM:   images: [ { localFile: [Object] } ]
5:40:48 PM: }
5:40:48 PM: warning Unsafe builtin method was used, future builds will need to rebuild all pages
5:40:48 PM: warning WebpackError: Unsafe builtin usage fs.existsSync:
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:38:1
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:46:1
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:308:1
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:226:1
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:411:1
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:63:12
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:46:26
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:94:20
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:105:20
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:352:14
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:338:21
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:363:5
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:82:12
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/autoprefixer.js:16:12
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/gatsby-ssr.js:54:38
5:40:48 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/.cache/api-runner-ssr.js:72:22
5:40:48 PM:   36 |     return filenessCache[file]
5:40:48 PM:   37 |   }
5:40:48 PM: > 38 |   var result = fs.existsSync(file) && fs.statSync(file).isFile()
5:40:48 PM:      | ^
5:40:48 PM:   39 |   if (!process.env.BROWSERSLIST_DISABLE_CACHE) {
5:40:48 PM:   40 |     filenessCache[file] = result
5:40:48 PM:   41 |   }
5:40:49 PM: warning WebpackError: Unsafe builtin usage fs.statSync:
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:38:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:46:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:308:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:226:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:411:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:63:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:46:26
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:94:20
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:105:20
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:352:14
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:338:21
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:363:5
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:82:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/autoprefixer.js:16:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/gatsby-ssr.js:54:38
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/.cache/api-runner-ssr.js:72:22
5:40:49 PM:   36 |     return filenessCache[file]
5:40:49 PM:   37 |   }
5:40:49 PM: > 38 |   var result = fs.existsSync(file) && fs.statSync(file).isFile()
5:40:49 PM:      | ^
5:40:49 PM:   39 |   if (!process.env.BROWSERSLIST_DISABLE_CACHE) {
5:40:49 PM:   40 |     filenessCache[file] = result
5:40:49 PM:   41 |   }
5:40:49 PM: warning WebpackError: Unsafe builtin usage fs.existsSync:
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:38:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:320:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:49:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:308:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:226:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:411:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:63:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:46:26
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:94:20
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:105:20
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:352:14
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:338:21
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:363:5
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:82:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/autoprefixer.js:16:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/gatsby-ssr.js:54:38
5:40:49 PM:   36 |     return filenessCache[file]
5:40:49 PM:   37 |   }
5:40:49 PM: > 38 |   var result = fs.existsSync(file) && fs.statSync(file).isFile()
5:40:49 PM:      | ^
5:40:49 PM:   39 |   if (!process.env.BROWSERSLIST_DISABLE_CACHE) {
5:40:49 PM:   40 |     filenessCache[file] = result
5:40:49 PM:   41 |   }
5:40:49 PM: warning WebpackError: Unsafe builtin usage fs.statSync:
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:38:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:320:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:49:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:308:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:226:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:411:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:63:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:46:26
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:94:20
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:105:20
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:352:14
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:338:21
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:363:5
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:82:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/autoprefixer.js:16:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/gatsby-ssr.js:54:38
5:40:49 PM:   36 |     return filenessCache[file]
5:40:49 PM:   37 |   }
5:40:49 PM: > 38 |   var result = fs.existsSync(file) && fs.statSync(file).isFile()
5:40:49 PM:      | ^
5:40:49 PM:   39 |   if (!process.env.BROWSERSLIST_DISABLE_CACHE) {
5:40:49 PM:   40 |     filenessCache[file] = result
5:40:49 PM:   41 |   }
5:40:49 PM: warning WebpackError: Unsafe builtin usage fs.readFileSync:
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:85:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:322:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:49:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:308:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:226:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:411:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:63:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:46:26
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:94:20
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:105:20
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:352:14
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:338:21
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:363:5
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:82:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/autoprefixer.js:16:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/gatsby-ssr.js:54:38
5:40:49 PM:   83 |
5:40:49 PM:   84 | function parsePackage (file) {
5:40:49 PM: > 85 |   var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file))
5:40:49 PM:      | ^
5:40:49 PM:   86 |   if (config.browserlist && !config.browserslist) {
5:40:49 PM:   87 |     throw new BrowserslistError(
5:40:49 PM:   88 |       '`browserlist` key instead of `browserslist` in ' + file
5:40:49 PM: warning WebpackError: Unsafe builtin usage fs.existsSync:
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:38:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:331:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:49:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:308:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:226:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:411:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:63:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:46:26
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:94:20
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:105:20
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:352:14
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:338:21
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:363:5
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:82:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/autoprefixer.js:16:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/gatsby-ssr.js:54:38
5:40:49 PM:   36 |     return filenessCache[file]
5:40:49 PM:   37 |   }
5:40:49 PM: > 38 |   var result = fs.existsSync(file) && fs.statSync(file).isFile()
5:40:49 PM:      | ^
5:40:49 PM:   39 |   if (!process.env.BROWSERSLIST_DISABLE_CACHE) {
5:40:49 PM:   40 |     filenessCache[file] = result
5:40:49 PM:   41 |   }
5:40:49 PM: warning WebpackError: Unsafe builtin usage fs.existsSync:
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:38:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:335:9
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:49:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:308:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:226:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:411:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:63:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:46:26
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:94:20
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:105:20
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:352:14
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:338:21
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:363:5
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:82:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/autoprefixer.js:16:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/gatsby-ssr.js:54:38
5:40:49 PM:   36 |     return filenessCache[file]
5:40:49 PM:   37 |   }
5:40:49 PM: > 38 |   var result = fs.existsSync(file) && fs.statSync(file).isFile()
5:40:49 PM:      | ^
5:40:49 PM:   39 |   if (!process.env.BROWSERSLIST_DISABLE_CACHE) {
5:40:49 PM:   40 |     filenessCache[file] = result
5:40:49 PM:   41 |   }
5:40:49 PM: warning WebpackError: Unsafe builtin usage fs.existsSync:
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:38:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:202:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:49:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/node.js:200:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:433:1
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:63:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:46:26
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:94:20
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:105:20
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:352:14
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:338:21
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:363:5
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/lazy-result.es6:82:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/autoprefixer.js:16:12
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/gatsby-ssr.js:54:38
5:40:49 PM:     at JAMstack-Course/.cache/api-runner-ssr.js:72:22
5:40:49 PM:   36 |     return filenessCache[file]
5:40:49 PM:   37 |   }
5:40:49 PM: > 38 |   var result = fs.existsSync(file) && fs.statSync(file).isFile()
5:40:49 PM:      | ^
5:40:49 PM:   39 |   if (!process.env.BROWSERSLIST_DISABLE_CACHE) {
5:40:49 PM:   40 |     filenessCache[file] = result
5:40:49 PM:   41 |   }
5:40:49 PM: success Building static HTML for pages - 7.760s - 19/19 2.45/s
5:40:49 PM: info Generated public/sw.js, which will precache 7 files, totaling 603270 bytes.
5:40:49 PM: The following pages will be precached:
5:40:49 PM: /offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback/index.html
5:40:49 PM: success onPostBuild - 0.257s
5:41:02 PM: success Caching JavaScript and CSS webpack compilation - 39.201s
5:41:06 PM: success Caching HTML renderer compilation - 25.353s
5:41:06 PM: info Done building in 164.99539487 sec
5:41:06 PM: ​
5:41:06 PM: (build.command completed in 2m 45.5s)
5:41:06 PM: ​
5:41:06 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:41:06 PM:   3. onBuild command from @netlify/plugin-gatsby                
5:41:06 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:41:06 PM: ​
5:41:07 PM: ​
5:41:07 PM: (@netlify/plugin-gatsby onBuild completed in 34ms)
5:41:07 PM: ​
5:41:07 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:41:07 PM:   4. Functions bundling                                         
5:41:07 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:41:07 PM: ​
5:41:07 PM: Packaging Functions from netlify/functions directory:
5:41:07 PM:  - gatsby/gatsby.js
5:41:07 PM: ​
5:41:08 PM: ​
5:41:08 PM: (Functions bundling completed in 1.2s)
5:41:08 PM: ​
5:41:08 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:41:08 PM:   5. onPostBuild command from @netlify/plugin-gatsby            
5:41:08 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:41:08 PM: ​
5:41:10 PM: ​
5:41:10 PM: (@netlify/plugin-gatsby onPostBuild completed in 2.5s)
5:41:10 PM: ​
5:41:10 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:41:10 PM:   6. Deploy site                                                
5:41:10 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:41:10 PM: ​
5:41:10 PM: Starting to deploy site from 'public'
5:41:10 PM: Creating deploy tree asynchronously
5:41:11 PM: Creating deploy upload records
5:41:13 PM: 292 new files to upload
5:41:13 PM: 1 new functions to upload
5:41:27 PM: Site deploy was successfully initiated
5:41:27 PM: ​
5:41:27 PM: (Deploy site completed in 16.9s)
5:41:27 PM: ​
5:41:27 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:41:27 PM:   Netlify Build Complete                                        
5:41:27 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:41:27 PM: ​
5:41:27 PM: (Netlify Build completed in 3m 14.8s)
5:41:28 PM: Caching artifacts
5:41:28 PM: Started saving node modules
5:41:28 PM: Finished saving node modules
5:41:28 PM: Started saving build plugins
5:41:28 PM: Finished saving build plugins
5:41:28 PM: Started saving pip cache
5:41:28 PM: Finished saving pip cache
5:41:28 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
5:41:28 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
5:41:28 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
5:41:28 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
5:41:28 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
5:41:28 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
5:41:28 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
5:41:28 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
5:41:28 PM: Started saving go dependencies
5:41:28 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
5:41:30 PM: Starting post processing
5:41:30 PM: Post processing - HTML
5:41:30 PM: Build script success
5:41:30 PM: Processing form - contact
5:41:30 PM: Detected form fields:
5:41:30 PM:  - name
5:41:31 PM:  - email
5:41:31 PM:  - phone
5:41:31 PM:  - message
5:41:32 PM: Post processing - header rules
5:41:32 PM: Post processing - redirect rules
5:41:32 PM: Post processing done
5:41:32 PM: Site is live ✨
5:42:24 PM: Finished processing build request in 5m19.328227521s
```

Update:
I have also noticed that now on my phone it actually does render a product page, but not in its entirety, ***and*** the page does not actually even function at all i.e. it can't even pick up on a button click or anything, it's just rendered the page and stops functioning...

Thus, it is still able to render the following after I click on any given product which the desktop is not able to pick up at all on...
[image: My Iphone Screenshot]

***Please try for yourselves as I think it may help in solving this bug...***

My Github repo for the frontend is as follows:
https://github.com/seanmodd/jamstack-final-frontend
My GitHub repo for the backend is as follows:
https://github.com/seanmodd/jamstack-final-backend
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocked loading mixed active content “http://54.67.112.47:1337/graphql”

you can't load http from an https webpage